# dotted symbols in equations

Tags: symbols, equations

I am writing a mathematical equation in LaTeX but want some of the symbols to be represented by dotted line segments. In practice I want to use `\sqcup`, which consists of three line segments, and want each of them to be replaced by a dotted line. Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: it seems I could use tikz to do this, but hopefully there is a simpler option. In any case any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* a TikZ solution.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*\Dottedsqcupmaxdots{7}
\newcommand*\Dottedsqcupcircleradius{.7\pgflinewidth}
\newcommand*\DottedSqCupsquarefactor{1.8}
\newcommand*\everyscquphspace{\mspace{1.2mu}} % needs amsmath

\newbox\boxdottedsqcup
\newbox\boxDottedsqcup
\newbox\boxDottedSqcup
\newbox\boxDottedSqCup

\savebox\boxdottedsqcup{\ensuremath{\everyscquphspace}\tikz{\draw[dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off \pgflinewidth] (0,14.5\pgflinewidth) -- (0,0) -- (12\pgflinewidth,0) -- + (0,14.5\pgflinewidth);}\ensuremath{\everyscquphspace}}
\savebox\boxDottedsqcup{%
    \ensuremath{\everyscquphspace}%
    \tikz{
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\Dottedsqcupmaxdots} {
            \fill (0,2*\x*\pgflinewidth) circle (\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
            \ifnum\x<\numexpr\Dottedsqcupmaxdots-1\relax
                \fill (2*\x*\pgflinewidth,0) circle (\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
            \fi
            \pgfmathparse{2*(\Dottedsqcupmaxdots-1)*\pgflinewidth}
            \fill (\pgfmathresult pt,2*\x*\pgflinewidth) circle (\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
        }
    }%
    \ensuremath{\everyscquphspace}%
}
\savebox\boxDottedSqcup{%
\ensuremath{\everyscquphspace}%
    \tikz{
    \pgfmathparse{\Dottedsqcupmaxdots-1}
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
            \fill (0,2.2*\x*\pgflinewidth) circle (\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
%           \ifnum\x<\numexpr\Dottedsqcupmaxdots-1\relax
                \fill (2.2*\x*\pgflinewidth,0) circle (\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
%           \fi
            \pgfmathparse{2.2*(\Dottedsqcupmaxdots-1)*\pgflinewidth}
            \fill (\pgfmathresult pt,2.2*\x*\pgflinewidth) circle (\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
        }
    }%
    \ensuremath{\everyscquphspace}%
}
\savebox\boxDottedSqCup{%
    \ensuremath{\everyscquphspace}%
    \tikz{
    \pgfmathparse{\Dottedsqcupmaxdots-1}
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
            \fill (0,2.2*\x*\pgflinewidth) ++(135:\Dottedsqcupcircleradius) rectangle +(\DottedSqCupsquarefactor*\Dottedsqcupcircleradius,-\DottedSqCupsquarefactor*\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
%           \ifnum\x<\numexpr\Dottedsqcupmaxdots-1\relax
                \fill (2.2*\x*\pgflinewidth,0) ++(135:\Dottedsqcupcircleradius) rectangle +(\DottedSqCupsquarefactor*\Dottedsqcupcircleradius,-\DottedSqCupsquarefactor*\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
%           \fi
            \pgfmathparse{2.2*(\Dottedsqcupmaxdots-1)*\pgflinewidth}
            \fill (\pgfmathresult pt,2.2*\x*\pgflinewidth) ++(135:\Dottedsqcupcircleradius) rectangle +(\DottedSqCupsquarefactor*\Dottedsqcupcircleradius,-\DottedSqCupsquarefactor*\Dottedsqcupcircleradius);
        }
    }%
    \ensuremath{\everyscquphspace}%
}

\newcommand*{\dottedsqcup}{\mathbin{\usebox\boxdottedsqcup}}
\newcommand*{\Dottedsqcup}{\mathbin{\usebox\boxDottedsqcup}}
\newcommand*{\DottedSqcup}{\mathbin{\usebox\boxDottedSqcup}}
\newcommand*{\DottedSqCup}{\mathbin{\usebox\boxDottedSqCup}}

\begin{document}\noindent
\(1\sqcup2\)\\
\(1\dottedsqcup 2\)\\
\(1\Dottedsqcup 2\)\\
\(1\DottedSqcup 2\)\\
\(1\DottedSqCup 2\)
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I guess it should be `\mathbin`